# Error occurred while proxying request localhost3000 to http://localhost:5000/ [ECONNREFUSED]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, proxy, reverse-proxy

Basically, the front end is a react application. The back end is a normal express server.

```
client
 ┣ public
 ┣ src
   ┣ lotsOfJs........
   ┣ setUpProxy.js 
 ┣ Dockerfile
 ┣ package-lock.json
 ┣ package.json
 ┗ yarn.lock
server
 ┣ .gitignore
 ┣ Dockerfile
 ┣ index.js
 ┣ package-lock.json
 ┗ package.json
┣ .dockerignore
┣ .env
┣ .gitignore
┣ docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    build: ./client/

    ports:
      - "3000:3000"

    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./client:./app # when you edit local, reflect change in container

  server:
    build: ./server


    ports:

      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - /app/node_modules
      - ./server:./app   # when you edit local, reflect change in container
```

setUpProxy.js

```
const  {createProxyMiddleware}  = require('http-proxy-middleware')   
module.exports = function(app) {
   
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/auth/google', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }))
    app.use(createProxyMiddleware('/api/*', { target: 'http://localhost:5000' }))
}
```

When I try something like http://localhost:3000/api/* , following errors printed in frontend ide console

```
[HPM] Error occurred while proxying request localhost:3000/api/current_user to http://localhost:5000/ [ECONNREFUSED]
```

But localhost:5000/api/current_user is actually working.  I have tried to shut down the server.  But the error is the same.

The whole localhost:3000/api/current_user request is not sent to the backend container at all.

If I don't use docker compose, and run them in local, no error at all, proxy correctly works.

I wonder if the problem of the wrong config of docker-compose?